# wireless router - configuring for low-latency, high traffic environment

Tags: latency, router

I have a few questions about configuring a router to achieve low-latency, high speed throughput on a local area network that is not connected to the internet. I've read up on some stuff, but thought I would solicit some opinions here on what I've found and what I want to know....

1. Turn off SSID broadcast - it produces extraneous packets that all clients receive and reply (?) to. Not a huge deal, but it may help a bit.
2. Mixed-mode off - I should attempt to have all devices using the same standard (e.g. 802.11n) and turn mixed-mode off.
3. Any thoughts on security? Does having WEP or any of the WPA variants actually increase latency? Nothing super secure is going over this LAN so if turning security off made things better, that'd be cool.

Any other thoughts or things to focus on to create the low latency environment I'm trying to go for would be great. Links to webpages and papers are also cool. I'm open to go through a bunch of stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

All these steps don't really help to get better results. 
Things that influence the quality are how good your access-point is, how close to the wifi-router you are and how good the wifi-card is. I for example always have a ping from around 1 or 2 ms to my router (remember that this is for each way to the router and also back, so in reality I have less than one millisecond as receiving-time which is good enough for everything!). Wifi is normally always slower then a network-cable - even if you use draft-N.

I don't really see a "Why" in your question.

Comment: The "why" would probably help - I'm working in an environment where live computer music is being performed. Computers communicate over Wifi (we try to avoid wires even though they are better). 

Essentially, things worked fine for 15 computers. When we hit 30+, we had trouble syncing computers over the network because of increased jitter caused by increased traffic. I am trying to see if there can be any improvements to our Wifi environment.

Comment: ten you should try, to set up more then multiple wifi-networks on different channels - group just the stuff that needs direct connection between each others - and connect the access-points using GBit-Lan with Cat6 cables. The wifi-networks will work fine, if they are on different channels /frequences. Normally you can choose between 11 channels in your hardware. Then it should work better and is also more redundant ;-)

Comment: In addition to what BasisBit says I would add having the access point and the devices as much in the clear as they can. Having them next to metal or electrical cables can be a problem. If wireless devices need to talk between each other, most routers isolate wireless devices so they must go through the router you could turn that off. If you are streaming to multiple clients, maybe multicast.  Also if you must you could also switch bands like using a 802.11A router/cards.  I also hear MIMO is good for bad WiFi environments.